# How do i find and count unique values in nested JSON objects?

Tags: javascript

i have the following JavaScript

```
{
  "business": [
{
  "order_contents": [
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 85,
      "name": "product 3",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 84,
      "name": "product 2",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 84,
      "name": "product 2",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

What i am trying to accomplish is when the order comes through a function scans the JSON and creates an array with each unique product name and adds 1 to the quantity each time.

i have tried using a for loop but it loops it the amount of times but doesn't find the name and value in the nested object of each one, it comes back as name = 0 and the value being the individual nested object inside the main object.

Comment: What does your function look like which does the looping and adding to the quantity?

Comment: JSON is a string. It can be converted to a javascript Object using `JSON.parse(string)`, which can then be treated like any other Object.

Comment: What does the output array look like that contains names and counts?

Comment: I'm assuming you want output of something like `[{"product 2":15}]`?

Comment: Okay.. so are you're trying to reduce the array items based on their name into separate arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function like the beneath would work. Basically you pass the array as parameter and return an object that 1) gets a new property if the property does not exist yet (eg. the product id), and 2) adds to the count of items when the property does exist. The function below generates an output like: `{'product 1': 10, 'product 2': 1, 'product 3': 2}`

```
function getItems(input) {
  var arr = input, obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!obj[arr[i].name]) {
      obj[arr[i].name] = 1;
    } else if (obj[arr[i].name]) {
      obj[arr[i].name] += 1;
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
// example use
console.log(getItems(order_contents)); // outputs entire object
console.log(getItems(order_contents)['product 1']); // outputs 10
```

Comment: `!obj[arr[i].name]` should be `!(arr[i].name in ob)` since the property may exist but return a falsey value. It doesn't matter here though. ;-) Also more generic and less code to use: `var p = arr[i].name; if (!(p in ob)){obj[p] = 0;} ++obj[p];`.×Comments can't contain that content.×Comments can't contain that content.×Comments can't contain that content. Plus 1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you need unique names for each product... you can push the objects into a ***grouped array of objects*** then reduce the objects into single unique objects.

```js
var data={"business":[{"order_contents":[{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":85,"name":"product 3","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":84,"name":"product 2","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":83,"name":"product 1","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]},{"id":84,"name":"product 2","price":"1.99","quantity":1,"total":"1.99","ingredients":[],"extras":[]}]}]};

function buildData() {
 var items = data.business[0].order_contents, elems = [], groups = [];
 for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
  Array.prototype.push.call( elems, items[i] );
 }
 groups.push( groupBy( elems, function( item ) {
  return item;
 } ) );
 groupBy( groups, function( array ) {
  for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
   var obj = array[i].slice();
   Object.keys( obj ).map( function( p ) {
    var length = obj.length;
    if( obj[p].hasOwnProperty( "quantity" ) ) {
     obj[p].quantity = length;
    }
    groups[i] = obj[p];
   } );
  }
 } );
 function groupBy( array, f ) {
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach( function( o ) {
   var group = JSON.stringify( f( o ) );
   groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
   groups[group].push( o );
  } );
  return Object.keys( groups ).map( function( group ) {
   return groups[group];
  } );
 }

 return groups;
}

(function() {
 var old = console.log;
 var logger = document.getElementById( 'log' );
 console.log = function( message ) {
  if( typeof message == 'object' ) {
   logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify( message, undefined, 2 ) : message) + '<br />';
  } else {
   logger.innerHTML += message + '<br />';
  }
 }
})();

console.log( buildData() );
```

```html
<pre id="log">
</pre>
```

Comment: I think you missed "*…each **unique** product name*".

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of reinventing the wheel, so here is how you could use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) to answer your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const counts = (haystack) => objectScan(['business[*].order_contents[*].name'], {
  filterFn: ({ value, context }) => {
    context[value] = (context[value] || 0) + 1;
  }
})(haystack, {});

const data = { business: [{ order_contents: [{ id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 85, name: 'product 3', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 84, name: 'product 2', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 83, name: 'product 1', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }, { id: 84, name: 'product 2', price: '1.99', quantity: 1, total: '1.99', ingredients: [], extras: [] }] }]};

console.log(counts(data));
// => { 'product 2': 2, 'product 1': 10, 'product 3': 1 }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)